Romance movie set in Ireland. Woman travelling to meet boyfriend
I watched this movie 5 years ago on TV. I think it is an old movie. I don't know who the actor is.
It was placed in Ireland. The male and female protagonists are Irish. The woman wanted to meet her boyfriend in England. Henceforth, the Irish man was her tour guide in England.
I remember some dialogues of the film:

Don't go in Saturday its bad luck for travelling people.

Then the man and woman go to England, they stopped on a train station near a castle. They climbed up the castle, but the woman slipped badly and they missed their train. 
I just remember that much and want know what the title is. 

I think it is the movie Leap Year ( 2010 ) . Please check it.

Please, even if the asker accepted you answer, give more details about how your answer fits his question.
